# TTY keeps pressing enter

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, tty

I can't login to my ttys. The following happens:

1. I open any tty using Ctrl+Alt+Number
2. I enter my username
3. I press "enter"
4. The password is skipped due to another "enter"
5. After a few seconds the login name prompt and is getting skipped as well as the password prompt again.
6. Step 5 repeats infinitely.

=> So an "enter" is occurring again and again.

This effect appears to be **only on ttys**. On any other console/terminal/program whatever this does not occur at all.

Where could this problem even arise from?

EDIT:
This problem appears on my PC (external keyboard) as well as on my laptop.

Comment: Of course, you also tried a differnt physical keyboard? Or the other enter key?

Comment: This did not help.

Comment: [The same on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/500545/108618).

Comment: Actually it turns out to be a bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813873

According to this an upgrade to cosmic should do it.