# Console login prompt not providing enough time to enter password

Tags: linux, passwords, login, ubuntu-16.04

This is new to me - I run Ubuntu 16.04 server, and generally interact with it via SSH. Today I tried to log on locally, but when I did the password prompt gave me barely enough time to enter a password (if I *really* hustle.)

Otherwise, it is like if someone is pressing enter every second. I've searched, but couldn't find this behavior described anywhere.

[A video is worth a thousand pictures...](https://media.giphy.com/media/NRt4yd3XJxHQNpovNG/giphy.gif)

login.defs has a login timeout of 60 (I tried modifying to 65 but that made no difference). When connecting to my server via ssh everything works normally.

The password timeout is the same for sudo at the command line - I do not experience this problem connecting via virtual terminals over ssh from a different client, only at the console.

When I ssh from the console at this server to a different host, the password prompt also exhibits the same behavior. (ex: ssh to my router, the password prompt does this weird stuff)

Where should I be looking to troubleshoot this?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/q/1406417/432690), links from comments there leading to more questions, comments and links; finally [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1113704/693277).

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski Thank you! That seems to be exactly the problem, and switching to the proposed kernel 4.4.0-143 resolved it.